# How in Excel do I move data to 8 consecutive cells in another worksheet?

Tags: excel

How in Excel do I move data (a person's name, so text data) to 8 vertically consecutive cells in another worksheet in the same workbook?

I'm no programmer and have only just googled what VBA stands for; so if anyone suggests some code I'll need telling just what to do with it!

I have a list of 2,000 names (one name in each cell in column A of a worksheet), and I want each name to appear 8 times, in a block one below the other with a spare row between blocks, in column C of another worksheet. I need to give each block a consecutive descending number, with each row in the block having the same number. Is there a formula to automate this process? Finally, Col W needs to repeat Col C, but with empty cells in the 6th & 8th row of each block.

Comment: We are not here to write your code for you for free. Please read [ask]. -1 and voted to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need VBA to do this. The following formula, entered in the second sheet and copied down, will do what you want. Note that it assumes that the first name in the sheet 1 list is in cell A1.

```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,IF(MOD(ROW(A1),9)=0,"",ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/9,0)),1),"")
```

This approach can be applied to any column of data. Thus, to number the blocks of eight rows in descending order, you add a column (let's say column B of Sheet1) of consecutive numbers next to the original name data. Sort the column of numbers in descending order using Excel's sort feature and then use the following formula in the second sheet.

```
  =IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,IF(MOD(ROW(A1),9)=0,"",ROUNDUP(ROW(A1)/9,0)),1),"")
```

Notice that the only difference from the original formula is the column reference, which has changed from `Sheet1!A:A to Sheet1!B:B.

To take the further step of adding blanks in specified positions in the blocks of eight, it is possible to elaborate further these formulas, but the approach soon becomes unwieldy. I would recommend instead the following simpler formula, which puts a blank in the sixth row of each block of eight names.

```
  =IF(A1<>"",IF(MOD(ROW(A1)-6,9)=0,"",A1),"")
```

Instead of operating on the original range, you would apply the formula to the column of names (in the second sheet) that have already been broken up into blocks of eight.

If you then want to add a blank in another position, say 8, apply the simple expression--modified to use 8 in the `MOD` clause instead 6--to the column of names with the added blank in the sixth position.

[image: Worksheet with formulas and results]

After you've finished with all these steps, you can copy and special paste as values the final list of names with blanks in multiple positions and then delete the intermediate column.

Comment: ooh, interesting, I tried that and it DOES work, but only up to the 31st name (or cell 278 in the second sheet). Thereafter I only get a list of zeros, albeit in nice blocks of eight. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, wonder what's going on. Try my worksheet at [this link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/48805010/copy%20names%20in%20groups%20of%20eight.xlsx).

Comment: Wow. Like watching magic. You should feel chuffed (as we say in England)! Thanks.

Comment: there are a few other tweaks I need to make to the 'one-off' spreadsheet I'm creating. I don't know the protocol here for asking, even paying in some way, for assistance. Should I, may I, email you directly? Or is that not the done thing here? I've already upset Doorknob and I'd rather not exacerbate things.

Comment: here's my two remaining challenges should you (or anyone else) wish to accept them. My 8-name blocks in consecutive rows (with an empty row between blocks) are now in Col C - hooray. In Col A I need to give each block a consecutive descending number, with each row in the block having the same number. Is there a formula to automate this process? Finally, Col W needs to repeat Col C, but with empty cells in the 6th & 8th row of each block. ends.

Comment: Please see my amended answer, VaVaVeteran. Would suggest you modify your question to include the additional elements. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to solve the issue in VBA. I have done it for only 16 names in Col A. The number can be increased to any limit based on your convenience. The names in column A are repeated 8 times with a blank row in between the blocks of 8 rows in Column C of Sheet2. Herebelow is the listing:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
cnt = 1
cmt = 8
        For J = 1 To 16
            For k = 1 To 8
            Sheet2.Cells(cnt, 3) = Cells(J, 1)
            Sheet2.Rows(cmt).Insert
                cnt = cnt + 1
            Next
            cmt = cmt + 8

        Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Gosh Rangan, thanks. What do I do with this listing? @Doorknob: I wasn't specifically asking for code, indeed wasn't sure that code was needed. I was asking for advice. I'm not surprised that I've been given an answer in VBA, but don't know what I'm to do next

Comment: ah, youtube indicates that Alt-F11 might be important...let the learning begin